# What non-obvious functions work on neural network objects?

Tags: neural-networks

I've learned in a recent Virtual Conference that I can use `Take` to get a subnetwork from a neural network object, so e.g.

```
net = NetChain[{5, LogisticSigmoid, 6, LogisticSigmoid, 7}];
Take[net,2]
```

will return a new neural network with only the first two layers of `net`. `Take[net,-2]` will get me the last two layers. This seems to be undocumented (at least in [`Take`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Take.html) and in [the neural networks overview](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NeuralNetworks.html)), but very useful.

So far, I've only found `Drop` and `TakeDrop` work on neural nets. `Part`, `Join`, `Append` or `Flatten` all don't work.

Are there any other useful functions for manipulating networks? For example, adding layers to an existing net (the inverse of `Take`) or joining two networks (the inverse of `TakeDrop`) would seem like useful operations. (e.g. to train each layer as an autoencoder, then remove the encoder "backend" and add the next layer.)

Comment: `Take` and `Drop` are mentioned in the docs for [`NetChain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetChain.html). No other functions are mention, as far as I saw.

Answer (score 5):

If you inspect the output of `UpValues[NetChain]` and `UpValues[NetGraph]` besides the `Take` and `Drop` there are only `Normal` and `VertexDelete` functions it seems.